# Forward call to method depending on runtime type

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I'm currently trying to build a in-memory read model on application startup. Therefor I use an event store that returns the event data as json. In my read model class there are handler methods for different event types that populate the read model.

For this I use the following parts:

Event interfaces that inherit a common IEvent interface. The events should only be messages without any logic on them.

```
public interface IEvent {}
public interface ISpecificEvent : IEvent { /* ... */}
public interface IOtherSpecificEvent : IEvent { /* ... */}
```

A serializer that converts the json to the actual types (depending on contents in the json data)

```
public interface IEventSerializer
{
    IEvent Deserialize(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e);
}
```

And a ReadModel class that contains `Consume` methods for the specific event types.

```
public class ReadModel
{
    private readonly IEventSerializer _eventSerializer;

    public ReadModel(IEventSerializer eventSerializer)
    {
        _eventSerializer = eventSerializer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventSerializer));
    }

    private void Consume(ISpecificEvent e)
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        // actual event handling - building the model
        Console.WriteLine("Consumed specific event.");
    }

    private void Consume(IOtherSpecificEvent e)
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        // actual event handling - building the model
        Console.WriteLine("Consumed other specific event.");
    }
}
```

Now when I come to how to dispatch the events to the consume methods I came up with three different options. The signature of the `DispatchEvents` methods are required by the third party library that is responsible to forward the events from the event store to my code. Simplified it looks like `EventStore.ReadEventsFromStream("streamName", e => DispatchEvents(e))`

**Option 1**

```
// dispatches events to the appropriate Consume method by first determening the
// actual type and performs a cast for it
public void DispatchEvents(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e)
{
    var deserializedEvent = _eventSerializer.Deserialize(e);

    if (deserializedEvent is ISpecificEvent)
        Consume((ISpecificEvent) deserializedEvent);

    if (deserializedEvent is IOtherSpecificEvent)
        Consume((IOtherSpecificEvent) deserializedEvent);
}
```

**Option 2**

```
// dispatches events by attempting a cast to a specific type. 
// Requires null check in the Consume methods
public void DispatchEvents(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e)
{
    var deserializedEvent = _eventSerializer.Deserialize(e);
    Consume(deserializedEvent as ISpecificEvent);           
    Consume(deserializedEvent as IOtherSpecificEvent);
}
```

**Option 3**

```
// dispatch events by using a dynamic type 
public void DispatchEvents(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e)
{
    dynamic deserializedEvent = _eventSerializer.Deserialize(e);
    Consume(deserializedEvent);
}
```

Which of the options above options would you consider the best and why? Do you have another suggestion on how to do it - preferably without having to put logic in the event classes?

Comment: I think that in option 3, it's the model consuming the event that would have to be `dynamic`, so that you can call `Consume` dynamically, i.e. do a late bound call that would be dispatched automatically. The event data does not have to be dynamic.

Comment: We don't review pseudocode. You need to include your actual code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not sure I understand. But then it could be that I simplified the code too much. Currently the `DispatchEvents` method would be part of the `ReadModel` class(es). They would be responsible for populating themselves by holding a connection to the event store and apply events as they come in. In this context, can you please further explain your suggestion?

Comment: @t3chb0t The options are pretty much the real code with simplified type names. The other code is only for providing context.

Comment: This code is simplified too much IMO. Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to avoid the if-else chains is to use double dispatch. Let the event data call the right `Consume` method of the event consumer. For this to work, the consumer methods need to be known to the event data. We can declare an interface for this:

```
public interface IConsumer
{
    Consume(ISpecificEvent e);
    Consume(IOtherSpecificEvent e);
    ...
}
```

The event data is declared as:

```
public interface IEvent
{
    void Raise(IConsumer consumer);
}
```

Now the consuming model implementing this interface can dispatch like this

```
public void DispatchEvents(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e)
{
    IEvent deserializedEvent = _eventSerializer.Deserialize(e);
    deserializedEvent.Raise(this);
}
```

And a specific event is implemented as:

```
public class SpecificEventData : ISpecificEvent 
{
    public void Raise(IConsumer consumer)
    {
        consumer.Consume(this); // Automatically calls the matching overload!
    }
}
```

Note also that the overload resolution happens at compile time.

Since the event data knows which `Consume` method to call right away, no if-else chains or switch statements are needed. Of all the algorithms and programming techniques I know, this seems the most astonishing to me.

---

Another option is to use C#7's pattern matching allowing you to switch on an object's type; however, while being slightly more elegant than an if-else chain, it is conceptually not any different from your option 1.

```
public void DispatchEvents(TypeThatContainsJsonEventData e)
{
    var deserializedEvent = _eventSerializer.Deserialize(e);
    switch (deserializedEvent)
    {
        case ISpecificEvent specificEvent:
            Consume(specificEvent);
            break;
        case IOtherSpecificEvent otherSpecificEvent:
            Consume(otherSpecificEvent);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. This is actually a very elegant way of handling it. (+1 for this) I think there is one downside to it: The event class has to know its consumers. When in my case there are multiple different read model classes that may or may not consume the same event types then the events will be filled with different `Raise` methods for the consumers. Do you have an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Added variant using `switch` with pattern matching.